# C# Получить форму родителя формы родителя

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть главная форма от нее я открываю форму от которой ещё одну из которой мне надо прочитать свойство в главной форме)) Как?

Comment: Ну передавайте в ваши формы ссылку на главную, в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Да сам уже понял

Comment: Window.GetWindwon(this)

Answer (score 0):

```html
using(var form = new ExampleForm()) {
    form.Owner = this.Owner;
    form.ShowDialog();  
  }
}
```